# How to remove headers and footers from webview in android which are getting added by default?

Tags: android, html, css, pdf, webview

I am programatically loading a html code into webview of android and then programatically making a pdf file from it and saving to disk. I can successfully create the pdf but some strange headers and footer are added because of which my pdf page size increases to 2 instead of 1. How do i remove that. Below is the image. I have removed the actual data from image but you can see the headers and footers which are covering up extra space. Those headers and footers are marked in red in the below image. 
[image]

code which generates pdf:
Part 1:

```
               printWrapper.setHtmlContent(billDetails);
               //webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
               webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, printWrapper.getHtmlContent(), "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);
               // Keep a reference to WebView object until you pass the PrintDocumentAdapter
               // to the PrintManager
               mWebView = webView;
```

Part 2:

```
String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
        PrintAttributes attributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
                .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
                .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("pdf", "pdf", 600, 600))
                .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).build();
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/");
        PdfPrint pdfPrint = new PdfPrint(attributes);
        pdfPrint.print(webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName), path, "Invoice.pdf");
```

Can anyone help me here to solve this?

Comment: what is the code? posting an image doesn't help much,

Comment: @mlegg added supporting code

Comment: I don't know how to remove headers but I have to add headers and logos on every page. So can you please help me with it. Can you show me the sample html code? or any other help pleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeease